# Reading a single integer back from GPU

Tags: android, opengl-es

Target: OpenGL ES 3.1

After each frame, I want to read back from my fragment shader the number of transparent fragments (i.e. fragments with 0 < alpha < 1) that the shader just wrote. Depending on this number, the CPU will then, in the next frame, use different rendering techniques (0 - normal, fast rendering; >0 --> switch to a order-independent transparency method with appropriate buffer size- which is much slower).

I guess I don't even need this data immediately; I can tolerate a delay of 1 frame (i.e. after sending frame N to GPU my CPU could read back the number from previous frame N-1 - if that would help speed-wise).

The question is: what is the best way to read this single integer back? 
Should I bind a FBO with GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER and then use glReadPixels to read the first pixel? or should I be using glMapBufferRange? Is it even a good idea? The point is, I need order-independent transparency, but a proper implementation of it (A-buffer with per-pixel linked lists) is a much slower rendering technique, so I want to detect if I need it at the moment (most of the time I won't be needing it) and only do it if there are really some transparent fragments on the screen.

Comment: How are you accumulating the non-opaque count? An atomic incremented by every fragment? Sounds dog expensive (atomics are horribly slow in most GPU implementations).

Comment: Are you trying to detect a mixture of non-opaque and opaque within a single draw, or do you know which draw calls are candidates for transparencies?

Comment: I don't need atomic increment, just a normal increment. It doesn't have to be atomic because I never read the value in the shader.

Comment: In the CPU, I have no idea if there's going to be transparency. I need to detect this in GPU and send a transparent fragment count back to CPU. The count does not have to be particularly precise. It can be delayed by 1-2 frames.

Comment: For posterity: I have decided for SSBO, aka Shader Storage Buffer Objects....

Comment: Atomicity is needed because you have hundreds of parallel threads on the GPU potentially trying to make updates to the counter concurrently. Non atomic updates might return a lower count than you actually get.

Comment: Yes, I have found that you are right (which means that a simple GLSL instruction 'localvar++' must get compiled into more than 1 native instruction on the GPU - why is that??) but actually in my specific user case that does not matter, I still can get away with some calibrating tricks on the CPU :)

Comment: Assuming a register-based architecture, most increment operations of a global variable will be "read value from memory into register", "increment value in register", "write value from register back to memory", so three instructions ...